# rvm list rubies error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I was troubleshooting readline and libcrypto errors this morning and ended up uninstalling RVM, Ruby and all gems.  I reinstalled RVM, Ruby and gems, but now when I do `rvm list` I get this:

```
rvm rubies
=* /home/username/.rvm/scripts/list: line 321: /home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/config: No such file or directory ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ ]
```

and now my app is throwing layout view errors all of a sudden. I haven't touched my code, and it worked fine before uninstalling/reinstalling.

I tried `rvm implode` and reinstalled again, and still no joy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same issue on OS X 10.8.2, with the latest Xcode. I:

- Installed RVM fresh.
- Compiled packages OpenSSL and Readline with llvm-gcc.
- Compiled Ruby with gcc-4.2 from Homebrew.

All was good until I noticed the output of `rvm list`.

There's already a [Github issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1254) for this, and it's been fixed, but it hasn't made its way to the stable branch just yet. Hang on, they'll get it.